# How to return all rows that exists in each group?

Tags: mysql, sql

**EDIT:**
[This](http://codex.cs.yale.edu/avi/db-book/db6/lab-dir/sample_tables-dir/DDL.sql) is the database. The question is:

> Find the course title which all the students whom their advisor is professor Katz took that course.

What I thought to solve this question:

1) Find ID of Prof. Katz.

2) Using that ID, find IDs of students whom Prof. Katz advises.

3) Using the founded student IDs, find all courses where Prof. Katz's advisees took.

4) Group the result by student IDs and get the rows present in *each* group, hence finding the course taken by *all* advisees of Prof. Katz.

I couldn't perform the step 4.

---

How to return all rows from a grouped table, where each returned row exists in every group of the table?

Comment: It's very unclear what the question is. Describe better, add sample data and expected output. Show us your current query, and describe what's wrong with it.

Comment: At the very least, post your sample data and the desired output.

Comment: @jarlh I have clarified my question.

Comment: Check out group by, having, and aggregate functions!

Comment: @jarlh I did but I guess I am not supposed to use an aggregate function to solve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Title 
FROM Course INNER JOIN Takes 
  ON Course.Course_ID = Takes.Course_ID 
WHERE Takes.ID IN 
(SELECT Student.Id 
 FROM Student INNER JOIN advisor ON Students.ID = Advisor.s_ID 
   INNER JOIN instructor ON Advisor.i_ID = Instructor.ID 
 WHERE Instructor.Name = 'Prof.Katz' )
```